# Undefined reference to methods of a templated class

Tags: c++, templates, typename

I'm trying to make a generic 2D array matrix class, but I am getting "error: undefined reference to `Zero::StaticMatrix::StaticMatrix(unsigned int, unsigned int)'" for my [] overloads and constructors of these two classes.

Here is a pastebin of the class definitions.  http://pastebin.com/Yq8fMAdy

p.s. I am using a friend helper class so I can access the _internal vector using something like `matrix[i][j]`, since there is no `[][]` overload.

Comment: You need to include the code **in** your post, not a link to it. If the code is too large to fit in a question you need to narrow it down to the specific code you are having problems with.

Comment: The above Pastebin 404s today, which is why we ask that code is embedded in questions. Voting to close.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a forward declaration of a template:

```
class StaticMatrixRow; // forward declaration
```

This is:

```
template< class T > class StaticMatrixRow;
```

You must declare `StaticMatrixRow` before using it in `StaticMatrix::operator[]`. Declare the operator and then define it after the declaration/definition of `StaticMatrixRow`.

Instead of having a single instance of a row iterator that you return references to, `StaticMatrix::operator[]` should create a new row iterator and return it.

`StaticMatrix::begin` and `StaticMatrix::end` are both declared as const, so these should return a `const_iterator` type.

Having `StaticMatrix::erase` makes no sense because they will change the size of `_internal` without changing the `_rows` or `_columns` members. `StaticMatrix::clear` also doesn't update these members; it should call `StaticMatrix::resize( 0, 0 )`.

`StaticMatrixRow::operator[]` should be using `(*_internal)[position]` since `_internal` is a pointer.

Since `StaticMatrixRow` is initialized with a const reference to a vector, `_internal` should be a pointer to a const vector. Since the vector is const, `StaticMatrixRow::operator[]` should return `const T &`.